# Не переводит значение Entry в int Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Куда я не ставил `get`, как я не переставлял местами, но все время появляется ошибка:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

```py
v0 = Entry(root, width=20,font=('Arial',11,'bold'))

V0 = v0.get()

print(int(V0))
```

Answer (score 0):

при запуске скрипта значение Entry будет равно пустой строке `""` что невозможно привести к числу.
добавьте значение `"0"` после создания. `v0.insert(0, "0")`

```
v0 = Entry(root, width=20,font=('Arial',11,'bold'))
v0.insert(0, "0")
V0 = v0.get()
print(int(V0))
```